# why is one ul lower than the other

Tags: html, css

i started working with html and css a couple days ago and im trying to make a navigator at the top of my website only i get a weird result that my second ul 3px lower is than my first while their both 50px in height. why is this?

[image]

```css
:root{
     font-size: 10px;
    }
    *{
     padding:0px;
     border:0px;
     margin:0px;
     color:black;
     text-decoration: none;
     list-style: none;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 1;
    }
    .nav{
     background: rgb(150,150,150);
     width: 100%;
     height: 5rem;
    }
    .nav ul{
     display: inline-block;
    }
    .nav ul a{
     display: inline-block;
    }
    .nav ul a:hover{
     background: rgb(100,100,100);
    }
    .pages a{
     font-size: 2rem;
     padding: 1.5rem;
    }
    .home{
     display: inline-block;
    }
    .home a li{
     font-size: 3rem;
     padding: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<head>
  <title>Mark Olieman</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="home">
      <a href=""><li>test</li></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pages">
    <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
  </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following. Also your HTML markup is wrong.

```css
:root{
  font-size: 10px;
}
*{
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px;
  color:black;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Make sure padding stays on the inside of the box */
}
.nav{
  background: rgb(150,150,150);
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
}
.nav ul{
  vertical-align: middle; /* Make sure everything align in the center */
}
.nav ul, .nav li, .nav a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a:hover{
  background: rgb(100,100,100);
}

.pages a{
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.home a{
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
<head>
  <title>Mark Olieman</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="home">
      <li><a href="">test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pages">
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding is being added to the item in the UL. This in particular.

```
.pages a {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

The `<a>` and anything else in general should go inside of the `<li>` tags.

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="home">
    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pages">
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```